# XSL Transformation [SOAP]

Tags: xslt, integration, soapui, maximo, inbound

Anyone can help me with this? I'm trying to transform the response from MAXIMO enterprise service with xsl mapping, and I have successfully transformed it but the problem is, it isn't returning any data when I submit a request.

Here's my xsl:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <SyncX1POMATREC>
            <X1POMATRECSet>
                <PO>
                    <SITEID>
                        <xsl:value-of select="string($var1_resultof_first/*[local-name()='SITEID' and namespace-uri()=''])"/>
                    </SITEID>
                    <PONUM>
                        <xsl:value-of select="PONUM"/>
                    </PONUM>
                    <REVISIONNUM>
                        <xsl:value-of select="REVISIONNUM"/>
                    </REVISIONNUM>
                    <POID>
                        <xsl:value-of select="POID"/>
                    </POID>
                    <RECEIPT>
                        <POLINENUM>
                            <xsl:value-of select="POLINENUM"/>
                        </POLINENUM>
                        <ITEMNUM>
                            <xsl:value-of select="ITEMNUM"/>
                        </ITEMNUM>
                    </RECEIPT>
                </PO>
            </X1POMATRECSet>
    </SyncX1POMATREC>
</xsl:template>
```

Here's the response:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soapenv:Body>
      <SyncX1POMATREC xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
         <X1POMATRECSet>
            <PO>
               <SITEID/>
               <PONUM/>
               <REVISIONNUM/>
               <POID/>
               <RECEIPT>
                  <POLINENUM/>
                  <ITEMNUM/>
               </RECEIPT>
            </PO>
         </X1POMATRECSet>
      </SyncX1POMATREC>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

**EDITED**

Here's the request XML from SOAP:

```
    <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:max="http://www.ibm.com/maximo">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <max:SyncX1POMATREC>
         <max:X1POMATRECSet>
            <max:PO action="AddChange">
               <max:SITEID>BEDFORD</max:SITEID>
               <max:PONUM>TEST42</max:PONUM>
               <max:REVISIONNUM>0</max:REVISIONNUM>
            </max:PO>
         </max:X1POMATRECSet>
      </max:SyncX1POMATREC>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Comment: Are there any namespaces in the input XML that you have forgotten to declare in the XSLT? That could be the probable cause of no data.

Comment: I really dont know much about the namespaces. Actually, it's my first time handling XSLs so I'm having some trouble and I dont know how to figure it out.

Comment: Please share the input XML which will help figure out the problem.

Comment: I edited the post, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The input XML has following namespaces `xmlns:max="http://www.ibm.com/maximo"` and `xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"` which are not declared in the XSLT. You need to declare these namespaces in the XSLT to access the associated XML elements.

In the XSLT, the elements need to accessed using the prefix declared for the namespace, in this case, it would be `max` i.e. `max:SITEID` or `max:PONUM` and so on.

Below is the modified XSLT. Certain elements viz. `POID`, `POLINENUM` and `ITEMNUM` are not present in the input XML shared and hence no values appear in the output.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    xmlns:max="http://www.ibm.com/maximo" exclude-result-prefixes="soapenv max">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

    <xsl:template match="max:PO">
        <SyncX1POMATREC>
            <X1POMATRECSet>
                <PO>
                    <SITEID><xsl:value-of select="max:SITEID" /></SITEID>
                    <PONUM><xsl:value-of select="max:PONUM" /></PONUM>
                    <REVISIONNUM><xsl:value-of select="max:REVISIONNUM" /></REVISIONNUM>
                    <POID><xsl:value-of select="POID" /></POID>
                    <RECEIPT>
                        <POLINENUM><xsl:value-of select="POLINENUM" /></POLINENUM>
                        <ITEMNUM><xsl:value-of select="ITEMNUM" /></ITEMNUM>
                    </RECEIPT>
                </PO>
            </X1POMATRECSet>
        </SyncX1POMATREC>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output

```
<SyncX1POMATREC>
    <X1POMATRECSet>
        <PO>
            <SITEID>BEDFORD</SITEID>
            <PONUM>TEST42</PONUM>
            <REVISIONNUM>0</REVISIONNUM>
            <POID />
            <RECEIPT>
                <POLINENUM />
                <ITEMNUM />
            </RECEIPT>
        </PO>
    </X1POMATRECSet>
</SyncX1POMATREC>
```

Comment: I am not sure what issue you are facing but based on the input XML that you have shared the output received can be verified at following online tool. [http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/94hvTyH](http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/94hvTyH)

Comment: Thanks for the tips! Ill try to figure it out and then post the answer here.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to ignore the namespaces by using `[local-name() =`, which you had the start of in your original question, and going straight to the element with `//*`:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <SyncX1POMATREC>
            <X1POMATRECSet>
                <PO>
                    <SITEID>
                        <xsl:value-of select="//*[local-name() = 'SITEID']"/>
                    </SITEID>
                    <PONUM>
                        <xsl:value-of select="//*[local-name() = 'PONUM']"/>
                    </PONUM>
                    <REVISIONNUM>
                        <xsl:value-of select="//*[local-name() = 'REVISIONNUM']"/>
                    </REVISIONNUM>
                    <POID>
                        <xsl:value-of select="//*[local-name() = 'POID']"/>
                    </POID>
                    <RECEIPT>
                        <POLINENUM>
                            <xsl:value-of select="//*[local-name() = 'POLINENUM']"/>
                        </POLINENUM>
                        <ITEMNUM>
                            <xsl:value-of select="//*[local-name() = 'ITEMNUM']"/>
                        </ITEMNUM>
                    </RECEIPT>
                </PO>
            </X1POMATRECSet>
        </SyncX1POMATREC>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I wouldn't have posted it without checking it worked. There must be something in your local environment to sort out.

Comment: I'll try to figure out what to sort out in my local environment. Thanks for the help!